# Is it possible to run "AZ cli commands" using some .net library?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, kubernetes

is it possible to retrieve token to azure aks server (same which is in .kube/config), using Azure Credentials, programatically c#/.net 6.

I know that in powershell to retrieve it i can run "az aks get-credentials" (yaml).

Answer (score 1):

> Yes, it is possible to retrieve a token from an Azure server using Azure credentials programmatically in C#.

Below is the code snippet, which I have followed and it worked for me.

```
IConfidentialClientApplication client = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
              .Create("<Client-Id>")
              .WithClientSecret("<Client-Secret>")
              .WithAuthority("https://login.microsoftonline.com/Tenant-ID")
              .Build();

            List<string> scopes = new List<string>
            {
                "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
            };

            AuthenticationResult result = await client
                .AcquireTokenForClient(scopes)
                .ExecuteAsync();

            GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(
                new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
                    async (requestMessage) =>
                    {
                        requestMessage.Headers.Authorization =
                            new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);
                    }));       

            var res = await client.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes).ExecuteAsync();
            string token = result.AccessToken;
```

Retrieving the token

[image]

Comment: But it is a access token to Azure, but not to particular AKS, which next i can use in: KubernetesClientConfiguration

Comment: Use the below code.
```string resourceUrl = "http://AKSService";
var azSVcTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
string Token = azSVcTokenProvider.GetAccessTokenAsync(resourceUrl).Result;
Console.WriteLine("Access Token: " + Token);
```